# When is it appropriate to post the names of living people in a question?

Tags: discussion

Re: the question [Where did Francois Dusnesmil with his wife Eliza Champion and 3 children arrive in America?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/4068/where-did-francois-dusnesmil-with-his-wife-eliza-champion-and-3-children-arrive), the user is doing research for the descendant of the family in the question and she has posted the descendant's name.  Should we edit that person's name out of this question, and any questions like this that may show up in the future?

Obviously we post the names of living family historians whom we are citing, and some of us post under our own names.  However, it's not clear to me that the person who has asked our user this question has consented to have her name placed on the site.

Comment: "it's not clear to me that the person who has asked our user this question has consented" - even if they consented, it's not appropriate. They can join SE and submit themselves under their handle, and they can provide what info they want in their profile. That is the only way living individuals (other than reference to book authors in answer below) should ever appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, it's never appropriate to identify a living individual (except as the author of a book/other published material). If you see it, please edit the question to remove and flag for moderators to get the history 'bleached'.

(My fault I didn't spot this one when I transferred the contents of a comment to the main question).